# How to lock/prevent/check application launching?

Tags: android, authorization, credentials

I need to find way to prevent unauthorizes launching of any (okay any 3rd party, not built-in) applications in Android device.

Supposed use-case should look like: when user tries to launch let's say Twitter or Facebook app, one will be asked for credentials to launch them (either password or any other option). If credentials are valid - application(s) will be launched in normal way.

So the questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. If possible - how?